# Error generating Terraform during setup wizard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

Trying to go through the GCP cloud setup wizard to spin up our organisation and project structure.

All works fine until we get to the point of downloading the generated Terraform configurations - get the attached error.

There's also this error message popup:

> There was an error fetching the blueprint preview.

When I attempt to download the configurations without the `Resource hierarchy and IAM` it is successful.

Any ideas on what would be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Can you check if there is a more detailed error message in the developer console? Can you share a redacted version of what you configured during that step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through the wizard process again from start to finish, this time no errors. Unfortunately not able to pinpoint the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check you have the organization IAM permission at first.

- Organization Administrator (roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin)
- Refer - [Access control for organization resources with IAM](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#resourcemanager.organizationAdmin)